# how to store server key permanently? openconnect

Tags: bash, terminal, vpn

Is there a way to store the server key after a successful connection, 
the way ssh does?

No matter how many times I connect, I have to always type "**yes**" to 
accept the server key. I wish it would be accepted and stored forever.

```
###############################
amir@amirpc:~$ sudo openconnect uk.cisadd.com -u myusername
POST https://uk.cisadd.com/
Attempting to connect to server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
SSL negotiation with uk.cisadd.com
Server certificate verify failed: signer not found

Certificate from VPN server "uk.cisadd.com" failed verification.
Reason: signer not found
Enter 'yes' to accept, 'no' to abort; anything else to view: 

Connected to HTTPS on XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
###############################
```

can write bash script to run openconnect and escape **yes**?

Comment: Perhaps --no-cert-check ? But the fact that your server certificate verification fails is worrying

Answer (score 9, accepted):

best way is first time you login into server save your --servercert in clipboard like this

```
echo "password" | sudo openconnect  -u username  uk2.cisadd.com --servercert sha25:xxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 7):

I bet you can do that with the option `--no-cert-check`or having a valid SSL cert:

```
sudo openconnect --no-cert-check uk.cisadd.com -u myusername
```

Comment: Using openconnect v7.08, it seems they've removed the --no-cert-check option: `The --no-cert-check option was insecure and has been removed.`

Comment: So you need now a valid certificate

Answer (score 2):

You can use `--no-cert-check` if you don't care having your traffic decrypted. Otherwise use `--servercert=FINGERPRINT` where FINGERPRINT is the "Server key hash" as displayed in the certificate information.

Comment: The `--no-cert-check` option is no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem on OpenWRT and my solution was to install the 'ca-certificates' package.

```
# opkg install ca-certificates
```

Once I did this, openconnect stopped flagging 'signer not found'.

The benefit of this solution is that you're using the intended certificates and limiting your chances of compromising your network.

Answer (score 1):

There is no longer `--no-cert-check` option in *openconnect version 7.0.6* onward.
In this way, I did the following procedure to bypass this problem as a shell script:

Firstly, you need the server certification and you can find it as follows:

```sh
echo <password> | sudo openconnect <hostname> --user=<username> --passwd-on-stdin --no-dtls
```

Then you have to find `--servercert` value from the intended output like this:

```sh
...
SSL negotiation with xxxxxxx
Server certificate verify failed: signer not found

Certificate from VPN server "xxxxxxx" failed verification.
Reason: signer not found
To trust this server in future, perhaps add this to your command line:
    --servercert pin-sha256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  <--- Here it is
Enter 'yes' to accept, 'no' to abort; anything else to view: fgets (stdin): Operation now in progress
```

Finally, after copying the certification code you can write your bash script as follows:

```sh
echo <password> | sudo openconnect <hostname> --user=<username> --passwd-on-stdin --no-dtls --servercert pin-sha256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```